# What does calling concat with no parameters do in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax

What is the point/result of calling `concat` with no parameters? E.g.

**Code:**

```
 var board = [
  false, false, false, false,
  false, false, false, false
];
board = board.concat();
```

Comment: `String board[]` isn't JavaScript.

Comment: Doesnt look like Javascript indeed.

Comment: Go through : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: `concat()` is a ***function*** not a ***parameter***.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the post ..

Comment: @Adham I think it was phrased a bit confusingly so I edited the question...is that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Concat function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is used for concatenation of two Arrays in javascript.

For Example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5]

a = a.concat(b); // a becomes [1,2,3,4,5]
```

### Edit

**Using `concat` with no arguments can be used to copy an array**. For example:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = a.concat();
b.push(4);

// a is [1,2,3] and b is [1,2,3,4]
```

Read this from MDN concat source

> concat does not alter this or any of the arrays provided as arguments but instead returns a shallow copy that contains copies of the same elements combined from the original arrays. Elements of the original arrays are copied into the new array

Answer (score 1):

Note: `concat()` is a ***function*** not a ***parameter***.

If you call `concat()` without a parameter, you will get a new  array as a result. See the summary below.

```
var board = [ false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ];
board = board.concat(); // Will return a new copy of your board array.
```

You may provide an argument to the `concat(value1, value2, ..., valueN)` function:

> N Arrays and/or values to concatenate to the resulting array.

---

You can read up on the documentation here: [`Array.prototype.concat()` @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

**Summary**

The `concat()` method returns a new array comprised of this array joined with other array(s) and/or value(s).

**Example**

```
var alpha = ["a", "b", "c"];
var numeric = [1, 2, 3];

// creates array ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]; alpha and numeric are unchanged
var alphaNumeric = alpha.concat(numeric);
```